# node-rest-client: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Tags: node.js, node-rest-client

I am trying to call a REST API from node using node-rest-client. In the event that my call returns an error, I want to catch the error and report it to the caller.

I am trying this with Postman, unfortunately this only works once. When I press send the second time, my node.js program crashes with the error "Can't set headers after they are sent."

I am new at node.js, so any help is highly appreciated!

```
//app stuff
const client_id = "x";
const client_secret = "y";
const callback = "https://myurl;

// Basic Setup
var http     = require('http'),
    express  = require('express'),
    mysql    = require('mysql'),
    parser   = require('body-parser'),
    Client   = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();

// Setup express
var app = express();
app.use(parser.json());
app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

// Set default route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<html><body><p>Welcome to Bank API Wrapper</p></body></html>');
});

app.post('/authorize', function (req,res) {
    var response = [];

    if (typeof req.body.code !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.state !== 'undefined' ){
        var code = req.body.code, state = req.body.state;

        //conversion to base64 because citi api wants it this way
        var authorization = "Basic " + Buffer.from(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString('base64');

        var args = {
            data:{"grant_type":"authorization_code","code":code,"redirect_uri":callback},
            headers:{"Authorization":authorization,"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} 
        };

        //get access and refresh token
        client.post("https://sandbox.apihub.citi.com/gcb/api/authCode/oauth2/token/sg/gcb", args, function (citidata, citiresponse) {
            //console.log(citidata);
            //console.log(citiresponse);
        });

        client.on('error', function (err) {
            response.push({'result' : 'error', 'msg' : 'unauthorized access'});
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    } 
    else {
        response.push({'result' : 'error', 'msg' : 'Please fill required details'});
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});


// Create server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: The program has no problem with the "Please fill required details" part. The problem is with the section that says client.on('error'. It works only once. After that, I get the error "Can't set headers after they are sent."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this:

```
client.on('error', function (err) {
```

This register an error handler on the `client` but it never gets removed. The `client` is shared between requests so any errors on subsequent requests will still fire the old error handlers.

Instead you can listen for an error on the request. Something like this:

```
var request = client.post("...

request.on('error', function(err) {
    // handle error
});
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client#error-handling

Comment: Tried it and got this. Only client.on('error.").. catches the error.


events.js:165
      throw err;
      ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Error parsing response. response: [{"type":"bad request","code":"400"....

Comment: I solved it by moving var client = new Client(); within app.post. Thanks! Your comment that client is shared between requests is extremely useful! Thank you!

Comment: @JacksonNg I tested it myself and using a request error handler as I described does catch the error. It shouldn't be necessary to move the `Client` creation inside `app.post`.

Comment: funny it didn't work for me though. It seems that client.on caught the error but request.on doesn't.